# Linear equation of the Tangent function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Let's say we have the following equation:

$\tan(x+y)=a(\tan(x)+\tan(y))$, where $a$ is a nonzero real number.

What can we say about $x$ and $y$? Is there a general solution?

Comment: What is $tan(A+B)$?

Comment: @Rumplestillskin If you are referring to the formula, I thought the question would be simpler in terms of linearity and not product.

Comment: Expanding the left-hand side looks like it would simplify things tremendously since you then have a factor of $\tan x+\tan y$ on both sides, effectively leaving you only two cases to consider.

Answer (score 0):

If $a=1$ then addition formula for tangent gives $\tan x \tan y=0,$ so one of the tanents must be $0,$ and it seems that's equivalent. But this $a=1$ case is a bit too simple. Still starting with the addition formula one might derive a relation between $x,y$ to characterize your relation.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$\tan(x+y)
=\dfrac{\tan(x)+\tan(y)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(y)}
$,
if
$\tan(x+y)=a(\tan(x)+\tan(y))$
then
$a = \dfrac1{1-\tan(x)\tan(y)}$.

Therefore,
given $a$ and either of
$x, y$, say $x$,
$1-\tan(x)\tan(y)
=\dfrac1{a}$
so
$\tan(y)
=\dfrac{1-1/a}{\tan(x)}
$.

Comment: Don’t you need to consider the case $\tan(x)+\tan(y)=0$ separately?